# Valarm not working in icalendar when it has multiple events

Tags: icalendar

Am using following Icalendar code to set multiple events in a single ics file... But when i tested it with outlook 2007, the remainder sets to none.

```
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    PRODID:- //Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN
    VERSION:2.0
    CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
    METHOD:PUBLISH
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTART:20120130T121000Z
    DTEND:20120130T131000Z
    UID:1620111121T075424707955
    DTSTAMP:20111121T075424
    DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:some descritption for event
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    SUMMARY:Summary
    PRIORITY:5
    CLASS:PUBLIC
    BEGIN:VALARM
    DESCRIPTION:Some description for alarm
    TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT30H
    ACTION:DISPLAY
    END:VALARM
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTART:20120201T233800Z
    DTEND:20120202T003800Z
    UID:1620111121T075424707955
    DTSTAMP:20111121T075424
    DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:some descritption for event
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    SUMMARY: Summary
    PRIORITY:5
    CLASS:PUBLIC
    BEGIN:VALARM
    DESCRIPTION:Some description for alarm
    TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT30H
    ACTION:DISPLAY
    END:VALARM
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR
```

When I use same format with only one event it is working fine... Help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. Did you figure out the issue?

Comment: no... not yet. If you will get, please advice

Answer (score 0):

It seems that reminders in calendar feeds are not supported by Outlook due to its design. Which is unfortunate because the feature is rendered nearly useless without something as basic as reminders.

The only way we were able to get reminders working was taking a calendar item from a feed, and then dragging it into one's personal calendar in Outlook. Not an effective, practical workaround at all.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to set these events in existing calendar than creating a new calendar?

Comment: The only two ways we discovered were either include a single event per file, or have the user drag individual items from a calendar feed into their own calendar. There is no way to specify what calendar to import calendar feeds into. Outlook always creates a new calendar and overlays that calendar with your other existing calendars...unfortunately. Let me know if you figure a solution out, thanks